# SQL join with other table and adding a case

Tags: php, mysql

This following query is telling me how many sales was at the same day.
also how many new users, and credits.

This is my working query (it works great!):

```
SELECT Substring(purchase.`date`,1,10)                       AS `DayDate`, 
                   Sum(Cast(Substring(purchase.`item`, 12) AS UNSIGNED))     AS `Credit`,
                   Count(1)                                                  AS `Sales`,
                   (SELECT Count(*) FROM enswitch_mobile_users WHERE Date(purchase.`date`) = Substring(enswitch_mobile_users.`creation_date`,1,10))  AS `New_users`
                        FROM   (SELECT item, date 
                                    FROM enswitch_new_iphone_purchases WHERE `status`=1
                                    UNION 
                                    SELECT item, date 
                                    FROM enswitch_new_android_purchases WHERE `status`=1) AS `purchase` 
                        WHERE purchase.`date` >= :from_date AND purchase.`date` <= :to_date
                GROUP  BY `DayDate` 
                ORDER  BY `DayDate` DESC
```

I am searching here in 3 tables.
`enswitch_new_android_purchases` `enswitch_new_iphone_purchase`
they both has item, user_id, status and date columns.
example for one entry:

`date`: `2012-08-01 16:24:30`
`item`: `xsalnx.sip.70`
`user_id`: `1337`
`status`: `1`

Also pulling the mobile_users amount from `enswitch_mobile_users`(id, creation_date, mobile id, ...) and grouping with specific day date.

What I am trying to do is to add a test if the user who bought, or the new user is a tester. if so I want to ignore this data on my query.

I'm saving the testers on a table called:
`enswitch_testing_devices` (id, name, mobile_id).

And I can join the data with `enswitch_mobile_users` (mobile_id column).

So far I tried to make it work but had no luck.. 
How can I do this query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below - just added a clause when you get the users - get all the users except test. Now a sample data and structure table would help. (I think you can re-write the query.)

```
SELECT Substring(purchase.`date`,1,10)                       AS `DayDate`, 
                   Sum(Cast(Substring(purchase.`item`, 12) AS UNSIGNED))     AS `Credit`,
                   Count(1)                                                  AS `Sales`,
                   (
                        SELECT Count(*) 
                        FROM enswitch_mobile_users 
                        WHERE 
                            Date(purchase.`date`) = Substring(enswitch_mobile_users.`creation_date`,1,10) 
                            AND enswitch_mobile_users.mobile_id NOT IN ( select mobile_id from enswitch_testing_devices WHERE 'is tester')
                    )  AS `New_users`
                        FROM   (SELECT item, date 
                                    FROM enswitch_new_iphone_purchases WHERE `status`=1
                                    UNION 
                                    SELECT item, date 
                                    FROM enswitch_new_android_purchases WHERE `status`=1) AS `purchase` 
                        WHERE purchase.`date` >= :from_date AND purchase.`date` <= :to_date
                GROUP  BY `DayDate` 
                ORDER  BY `DayDate` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not working, its still returning me the sales of the testers :/

Answer (score 0):

I manage to SOLVE this issue.

If any one wondered.

```
function search_daily_sales($from_date, $to_date ,$show_testers)
{
        // If not showing the testers
    if ($show_testers === false) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT Substring(purchase.`date`,1,10)                            AS `DayDate`,
                        Sum(CASE WHEN td.mobile_id IS NULL 
                            THEN Cast(Substring(purchase.`item`, 12) AS UNSIGNED) 
                            ELSE '0' END)                                         AS `Credit`,
                        Sum(CASE WHEN td.mobile_id IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS `Sales`,
                        (SELECT Count(*) FROM enswitch_mobile_users 
                            WHERE 
                                Date(purchase.`date`) = Substring(enswitch_mobile_users.`creation_date`,1,10)
                            AND enswitch_mobile_users.`mobile_id` NOT IN (SELECT mobile_id FROM enswitch_testing_devices))  AS `New_users`,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN td.mobile_id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END)    AS `tester`

                    FROM   (SELECT item, date, user_id
                                FROM enswitch_new_iphone_purchases WHERE `status`=1
                                UNION 
                                SELECT item, date, user_id
                                FROM enswitch_new_android_purchases WHERE `status`=1) AS `purchase` 

                    LEFT JOIN enswitch_mobile_users mu ON mu.id = purchase.user_id
                    LEFT JOIN enswitch_testing_devices td ON td.mobile_id = mu.mobile_id

                    WHERE purchase.`date` >= :from_date AND purchase.`date` <= :to_date
            GROUP  BY `DayDate` 
            ORDER  BY `DayDate` DESC";
    }
    else 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT Substring(purchase.`date`,1,10)                       AS `DayDate`, 
               Sum(Cast(Substring(purchase.`item`, 12) AS UNSIGNED))     AS `Credit`,
               Count(1)                                                  AS `Sales`,
               (SELECT Count(*) FROM enswitch_mobile_users WHERE Date(purchase.`date`) = Substring(enswitch_mobile_users.`creation_date`,1,10))  AS `New_users`
                    FROM   (SELECT item, date 
                                FROM enswitch_new_iphone_purchases WHERE `status`=1
                                UNION 
                                SELECT item, date 
                                FROM enswitch_new_android_purchases WHERE `status`=1) AS `purchase` 
                    WHERE purchase.`date` >= :from_date AND purchase.`date` <= :to_date
            GROUP  BY `DayDate` 
            ORDER  BY `DayDate` DESC";
    }

    $result = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)->bind(':from_date', $from_date)->
                                                bind(':to_date', $to_date)->execute();

return $result;
}
```